# How to resolve Google Maps API warning "X-Staticmap-Api-Warning: Error geocoding: center, marker 1"?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

For some addresses, google maps static api returns a 200 response, but image shows up blank with a yellow ribbon at the top right with this error message: "Maps error: g.co/staticmaperror":

[image: Static maps response with warning]

[Here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=4606%20Hickory%20Hill%20Ln&zoom=18&size=820x308&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:1%7C4606%20Hickory%20Hill%20Ln&key=%3Capi_key%3E) is an example URL.

ChromeDevTools Response Headers has this:

```
X-Staticmap-Api-Warning: Error geocoding: center, marker 1
```

Their [error message page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/error-messages) has this description:

> An error occurred while attempting to geocode the request. There are many variants of this message, depending on the element where geocoding failed (center, marker, visible, or path) and the number of elements that failed. One example of this warning is X-Staticmap-API-Warning:Error geocoding: marker 1, as shown in the above example.

But it doesn't explain how to fix this issue. Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: testing this I found two possible issues. For the address given there are multiple possible results in various parts of the USA - narrowing that address down to a specific city/state helped. The other is the marker portion of the code  - with that removed the map loaded fine when a specific state/city was appended to the addres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by [Professor Abronsius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603681/professor-abronsius), providing a descriptive address helps fix this.

Answer (score 1):

*An error occurred while attempting to **geocode** the request* usually means **no result** was found when geocoding the given addresses, in this case the address for (both) `center` and `marker 1` is incomplete:
**4606 Hickory Hill Ln**.

The Static Maps API uses the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding) under the hood to geocode addresses. As explained in [Geocoding Addresses Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices), *use the Geocoding API when geocoding **complete** addresses*.